# Is it possible to extend free monad interpreters?

Tags: haskell, free-monad

Given a free monad DSL such as:

```
data FooF x = Foo String x
            | Bar Int    x
  deriving (Functor)

type Foo = Free FooF
```

And a random interpreter for `Foo`:

```
printFoo :: Foo -> IO ()
printFoo (Free (Foo s n)) = print s >> printFoo n
printFoo (Free (Bar i n)) = print i >> printFoo n
```

It appears to me that it should be possible to intersperse something into each iteration of printFoo without resorting to doing it manually:

```
printFoo' :: Foo -> IO ()
printFoo' (Free (Foo s n)) = print s >> print "extra info" >> printFoo' n
printFoo' (Free (Bar i n)) = print i >> print "extra info" >> printFoo' n
```

Is this somehow possible by 'wrapping' the original `printFoo`?

---

Motivation: I am writing a small DSL that 'compiles' down to a binary format. The binary format contains some extra information after each user command. It has to be there, but is totally irrelevant in my usecase.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The other answers have missed how simple`free` makes this!  :) Currently you have

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}

import Control.Monad.Free

data FooF x = Foo String x
            | Bar Int    x
  deriving (Functor)

type Foo = Free FooF

program :: Free FooF ()
program = do
  liftF (Foo "Hello" ())
  liftF (Bar 1 ())
  liftF (Foo "Bye" ())

printFoo :: Foo () -> IO ()
printFoo (Free (Foo s n)) = print s >> printFoo n
printFoo (Free (Bar i n)) = print i >> printFoo n
printFoo (Pure a) = return a
```

which gives

```
*Main> printFoo program 
"Hello"
1
"Bye"
```

That's fine, but `iterM` can do the requisite plumbing for you

```
printFooF :: FooF (IO a) -> IO a
printFooF (Foo s x) = print s >> x
printFooF (Bar i x) = print i >> x

printFooBetter :: Foo () -> IO ()
printFooBetter = iterM printFooF
```

Then we get

```
*Main> printFooBetter program
"Hello"
1
"Bye"
```

OK great, it's the same as before.  But `printFooF` gives us more
flexibility to augment the translator along the lines you want

```
printFooFExtra :: FooF (IO a) -> IO a
printFooFExtra = (print "stuff before IO action" >>)
                 . printFooF
                 . fmap (print "stuff after IO action" >>)

printFooExtra :: Foo () -> IO ()
printFooExtra = iterM printFooFExtra
```

then we get

```
*Main> printFooExtra program
"stuff before IO action"
"Hello"
"stuff after IO action"
"stuff before IO action"
1
"stuff after IO action"
"stuff before IO action"
"Bye"
"stuff after IO action"
```

Thanks Gabriel Gonzalez for popularizing free monads and Edward Kmett
for writing the library!  :)

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for! I was sure that this is somehow possible, but didn't knew how. Thanks!

Comment: Could you maybe elaborate on why this strange function combination stuff in `printFooFExtra` is necessary?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean exactly, but you could write it as `printFooFExtra x = print "stuff before IO action" >> (printFooF (fmap (print "stuff after IO action" >>) x))`.  You basically make an "augmented" interpreter that instead of just doing the `printFooF` interpretation you do some stuff before hand and do some stuff afterwards.  The `fmap` is there to do the stuff before the continuation of `printFooF`.  Does that help?  If feel free to ask further.

Comment: @TomEllis I think you are missing the point that annotation is the same sort of traversal as is done by interpreter. I haven't tried, but I am pretty sure the following will work: `iter annotate $ (program >>= return . return)` will turn `Foo ()` into `Foo (Foo ())`, which then can be annotated with `annotate (Foo x y) = ...$ Foo x y; annotate (Bar x y) = ... $ Bar x y`

Comment: @SassaNF: I'm afraid I don't understand.  Could you give me a concrete implementation of what you are talking about?

Comment: Actually I think I understand what you're saying now.  Yes, you can indeed do the annotation by interpreting `Foo` in itself, taking advantage of the fact that the `Foo` action contains a string that is printed.  However, this is not a general solution.  What would you do if the "annotation" was to ring a bell before every action?  You can't do that by adding an extra action in the `Foo` monad, because there is no such action corresponding to ringing a bell.  It *has* to be done in `IO`.  Thus to keep the solution general I prefer to do it the way I presented.

Comment: Actuall @TomEllis is right. My 'interpreter' uses `cereal` to output a binary format so the type is `putMacroF :: MacroF (PutM b) -> PutM b`. Again thanks for this great answer. It is working like a charm for me.

Answer (score 5):

Here a very simple solution using the [`operational`](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Operational) package -- the reasonable alternative to free monads.

You can just factor the `printFoo` function into a part that prints the instruction proper and a part that adds the additional information, the standard treatment for code duplication like this.

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

import Control.Monad.Operational

data FooI a where
    Foo :: String -> FooI ()
    Bar :: Int    -> FooI ()

type Foo = Program FooI

printFoo :: Foo a -> IO a
printFoo = interpretWithMonad printExtra
    where
    printExtra :: FooI a -> IO a
    printExtra instr = do { a <- execFooI instr; print "extra info"; return a; }

execFooI :: FooI a -> IO a
execFooI (Foo s) = print s
execFooI (Bar i) = print i
```

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking for something like this?

Your original code would be

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}

import Control.Monad.Free

data FooF a = Foo String a | Bar Int a deriving (Functor)

type Foo = Free FooF

printFoo :: Show a => Foo a -> IO ()
printFoo (Free (Foo s n)) = print s >> printFoo n
printFoo (Free (Bar i n)) = print i >> printFoo n
printFoo (Pure a)         = print a
```

You can then define a simple wrapper function, and a recursive annotater that adds the extra info to each layer of `Foo` (obviously these can be as complicated as you like).

```
annotate :: Foo a -> Foo a
annotate (Free (Foo s n)) = wrapper (Free (Foo s (annotate n)))
annotate (Free (Bar i n)) = wrapper (Free (Bar i (annotate n)))
annotate (Pure a)         = wrapper (Pure a)

wrapper :: Foo a -> Foo a
wrapper n = Free (Foo "Extra info" n)
```

Now define some convenience constructors that define your DSL

```
foo :: String -> a -> Foo a
foo s a = Free (Foo s (Pure a))

bar :: Int -> a -> Foo a
bar i a = Free (Bar i (Pure a))
```

Which means that you can create `Foo a` objects just using the monad interface and your DSL

```
example = do
    i <- return 1
    a <- foo "Created A" i
    b <- bar 123 a
    c <- foo "Created C" b
    return c
```

Now if you load up GHCI, you can work with either the original `example` or with the annotated version

```
>> printFoo example
"Created A"
123
"Created C"
1
>> printFoo (annotate example)
"Extra info"
"Created A"
"Extra info"
123
"Extra info"
"Created C"
"Extra info"
1
```

Comment: That looks like it should work for me. I have to try it (ie refactor my code).

Comment: Two quick questions: a) is there a way to write `annotate` without having to write everything out? Possibly via `uniplate` or something? b) This requires me to add a `ExtraInfo` constructor to `FooF`, is there a way around that?

Comment: @Florian re. `uniplate` I'm not sure, I've never used that library. Possibly you can search around `Data.Typeable` and `Data.Generics` to get an answer, but I'm not very familiar with them. re. extra constructor, I don't see an obvious way to avoid the additional constructor, but I'd argue that you probably should have it - clearly your application needs it at some point, or you wouldn't be asking the question!

Comment: Think of it as an *package footer* (as opposed to header). Just without any additional useful information. Come to think of it I probably should just write some `addFooter :: Foo a -> FooWithFooter a` function and then write that to the file.

Comment: @Florian these two things are just catamorphisms.

Comment: @SassaNF how does that help me?

Comment: @Florian depending what you mean by "having to write everything out"

Answer (score 1):

Both things just traverse the structure and accumulate the result of inductive processing. This calls for generalizing the iteration through catamorphism.

```
> newtype Fix f = Fix {unFix :: f (Fix f)}
> data N a b x = Z a | S b x deriving (Functor)
> type Nat a b = Fix (N a b)
> let z = Fix . Z
> let s x = Fix . S x
> let x = s "blah" $ s "doo" $ s "duh" $ z 0
> let annotate (Z x) = s "annotate" $ z x;
      annotate (S x y) = s "annotate" $ s x y
> let exec (Z x) = print x; exec (S x y) = print x >> y
> let cata phi = phi . fmap (cata phi) . unFix
>
> cata exec x
"blah"
"doo"
"duh"
0
>
> cata exec $ cata annotate x
"annotate"
"blah"
"annotate"
"doo"
"annotate"
"duh"
"annotate"
0
```

---

Now let me explain in more depth what is going on, since there were some requests in the comments, and concerns that it won't be a monad anymore, if I use Fix.

Consider functor G:

```
G(X) = A + F(G(X))
```

Here F is a arbitrary functor. Then for any A we can find a fixed point (F and G are clearly polynomial - we are in Hask). Since we map every object A of the category to a object of the category, we are talking about a functor of fixed points, T(A). It turns out that it is a Monad. Since it is a monad for any functor F, T(A) is a Free Monad. (You will see it is obviously a Monad from the code below)

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor
           , TypeSynonymInstances #-}

newtype Fix f = Fix {unFix :: f (Fix f)} -- the type of Fixed point of a functor
newtype Compo f g x = Compo {unCompo :: f (g x)} -- composition of functors

instance (Functor f, Functor g) => Functor (Compo f g) where -- composition of functors is a functor
  fmap f = Compo . fmap (fmap f) . unCompo

data FreeF a x = Pure a | Free x deriving (Functor) -- it is a bi-functor, really;
                -- this derives functor in x

-- a special case of fmap - the fmap with unwrapping; useful to eliminate pattern matching
ffmap :: (a -> b) -> FreeF b a -> b
ffmap f x = case fmap f x of -- unwrapping, since now distinction between Pure and Free is not important
              Pure a -> a
              Free a -> a

-- Free Monad is a functor of fixed points of functor G(X)
-- G(X) = A + F(G(X))
type Free f a = Fix (Compo (FreeF a) f) -- fixed point of composition F . (FreeF a)


-- unfortunately, when defined as type, (Free f a) cannot be declared
-- as a Monad (Free f) - Haskell wants Free f to be with `a`
-- instance Monad (Free f) where -- this derives a functor in a at the same time;
--                          note that fmap will work in x, and is not meant
--                          to be equal to (m >>= return . f), which is in `a`
--   return a = Fix $ Compo $ Pure a
--   (Fix (Compo (Pure a))) >>= f  = f a
--   (Fix (Compo (Free fx))) >>= f = Fix $ Compo $ Free $ fmap (>>= f) fx

ret :: (Functor f) => a -> Free f a -- yet it is a monad: this is return
ret = Fix . Compo . Pure

-- and this is >>= of the monad
bind :: (Functor f) => Free f a -> (a -> Free f b) -> Free f b
bind (Fix (Compo (Pure a))) f = f a
bind (Fix (Compo (Free fx))) f = Fix $ Compo $ Free $ fmap (`bind` f) fx

-- Free is done

-- here is your functor FooF
data FooF x = Z Int x | S String x deriving (Functor)

type Foo x = Free FooF x

-- catamorphism for an algebra phi "folds" any F(X) (represented by fixed point of F)
-- into X
cata :: (Functor f) => (f x -> x) -> Fix f -> x
cata phi = phi . fmap (cata phi) . unFix

-- helper functions to construct "Foo a"
z :: Int -> Foo a -> Foo a
z x = Fix . Compo . Free . Z x

s :: String -> Foo a -> Foo a
s x = Fix . Compo . Free . S x

tip :: a -> Foo a
tip = ret

program :: Foo (IO ())
program = s "blah" $ s "doo" $ s "duh" $ z 0 $ tip $ return ()

-- This is essentially a catamorphism; I only added a bit of unwrapping
cata' :: (Functor f) => (f a -> a) -> Free f a -> a
cata' phi = ffmap (phi . fmap (cata' phi)) . unCompo . unFix

exec (Z x y) = print x >> y
exec (S x y) = print x >> y

annotate (Z x y) = s "annotated Z" $ z x y
annotate (S x y) = s "met S" $ s x y

main = do
         cata' exec program
         cata' exec $ cata' annotate (program `bind` (ret . ret))
           -- cata' annotate (program >>= return . return)
           -- or rather cata' annotate $ fmap return program
```

`program` is `Foo (IO ())`. `fmap` in `a` (remember FreeF is a bi-functor - we need the fmap in `a`) can turn `program` into `Foo (Foo (IO ()))` - now catamorphism for annotate can construct a new `Foo (IO ())`.

Note that `cata'` is `iter` from `Control.Monad.Free`.

Comment: If you add some types and give a bit more of an explanation of `cata` (types are a good start) than this would be a great answer.

Comment: Also writing this as normal Haskell code vs for GHCi is probably a good idea

Comment: @Sassa By using `Fix` you would lose the ability to perform monadic bind, which could be a problem depending on the use case.

Comment: @DanielDíazCarrete I am not sure that is the case. Fix is another way to write Free, the free monad. You can observe that `Nat a b` is no different from `Free f a b = Pure a | Free b (f (Free f a b))`

Comment: @jozefg how about now? (i don't compete for knowledge of Haskell packages :) TomEllis already won that prize)

Comment: @SassaNF Am I right, that your (updated) answer is basically the same the one from TomEllis? When I first saw your (pre update) answer I was like "how is that supposed to help me".

Comment: @Florian I think the end result is the same: use iter; although I took detour investigating how Free Monad is related to Fix, and how annotation can be done using the same mechanism without printing the annotations.

Comment: @SassaNF so basically you reinvented Free Monads in your first attempt? ;)

Comment: @Florian I don't pretend to have reinvented them :) But I had to wrangle with the type-system to be able to show the link between Free Monads and Fixed points - and catamorphisms. If you knew all of that, then take it as a learning exercise for me :)

Comment: @SassaNF I didn't know about the catamorphims, but I was pretty sure `free` was implemented with `fix`. In the end I am just happy that I can no run around and show others that something strangesounding as `free monads` can be used to great effect in a real world application ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to slightly modify the original interpreter (by changing how the terminal case is handled)

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}

import Control.Monad.Free
import Control.Monad.Morph
import Pipes

data FooF a = Foo String a | Bar Int a deriving (Functor)

printFoo :: Free FooF a -> IO a
printFoo (Free (Foo s n)) = print s >> printFoo n
printFoo (Free (Bar i n)) = print i >> printFoo n
printFoo (Pure a)         = return a
```

...then there's a way to add extra actions without modifying the functor or having to repurpose its constructors, while still being able to reuse the interpreter.

The solution uses the `pipes` and `mmorph` packages.

First you have to define a sort of "pre-interpeter" that lifts the free monad into a `Producer` from `pipes`. The `yield ()` statements in the producer signify the points at which an extra action is inserted.

```
pre :: Free FooF a -> Producer () (Free FooF) a
pre (Free (Foo s n)) = lift (Free . Foo s $ return ()) >> yield () >> pre n
pre (Free (Bar i n)) = lift (Free . Bar i $ return ()) >> yield () >> pre n
pre (Pure a)         = lift . Pure $ a
```

(In a more complex example the `yield` statements could carry extra information, like log messages.)

Then you write a function that applies the `printFoo` interpreter *underneath* the `Producer`, using `hoist` from `mmorph`:

```
printFooUnder :: Producer () (Free FooF) a -> Producer () IO a
printFooUnder = hoist printFoo
```

So, we have a function that "interprets" the free monad into `IO`, but at some points emits `()` values that we must decide how to handle.

Now we can define an extended interpreter that reuses the old interpreter:

```
printFooWithReuse :: Show a => Free FooF a -> IO () 
printFooWithReuse foo = do
    finalv <- runEffect $ for (printFooUnder . pre $ foo) 
                              (\_ -> lift (print "extra info"))
    print finalv
```

After testing it, it seems to work:

```
printFooWithReuse $ Free (Foo "nah" (Pure 4))
-- > "nah"
-- > "extra info"
-- > 4
```

If you happen to want to insert the extra actions manually, then your can eschew writing the "pre-interpreter" and work directly in the `Producer () (Free FooF)` monad.

(This solution could also be achieved by layering a free monad transformer instead of a `Producer`. But I think using a `Producer` is a bit easier.)