# Is it possible to extend free monad parsers?

Tags: haskell, free-monad

This is a follow up to [Is it possible to extend free monad interpreters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20564633/is-it-possible-to-extend-free-monad-interpreters) or better the reverse.

I recently revisited the project that the previous question stemmed from. This time I try to parse the file into the data structure.

Problem is that I have no clue on how to achieve this. While writing he (`cereal` based) parsers is unproblematic and it is working as long as I only parse into the `FooF` type, I have no idea on how to how to create the interleaved `Functor` (correct terminology?).

Note:

- At this point I am looking only for clues on how to achieve this.
- There is no code yet that I can provide.
- Please refer to the code in the linked question and the accepted answer for datatypes.

Comment: There was [a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21395407/combining-free-types/21395655#21395655) about how to merge functors of a free monad together.  Check out the answers to that question (I wrote one of them, but the others are good, too) and let me know if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: @GabrielGonzalez Thats more or less the same solution that was given in my first/linked question. I am looking for the *other way around*, that is, constructing the structure from parsed input.

Comment: You want to parse into `Free FooF` instead of parsing into `FooF x`? I presume you can parse into `FooF x` for all `x` that you can parse?

Comment: Do you mean to parse some other junk before and after each occurrence of free (like the junk that was written in the linked question)? Since the parser libraries are based on type classes, the easiest thing might be to make a type that represents what you surround your data with. `data Surrounded a b f x = Surrounded a (f x) b`. Then, if you are adding, say a `String` before and an `Int` after, you would be parsing into `Free (Surrounded String Int FooF)`.

Comment: @Cirdec yep ... I recognised on the way home that this is probably the way to go. I'll try to implement that, maybe you can rephrase this into a short answer?

Comment: Based on one of your comments on the other question, are you looking for a way to write `getMacroF :: Get b -> MacroF (Get b)`, where `MacroF` is your `FooF` and somehow find the inverse of `iterM` such that `reverseIterM :: (Monad m, Functor f) => (m a -> f (m a)) -> m a -> Free f a` can be applied to `getMacroF` to do the opposite of what you were doing in the other question? so `reverseIterM getMacroF` is the parser for what `iterM putMacroF` pretty prints?

Comment: If that's what you want, `getMacroF` is the `get` method of `FooF`'s `Serialize` instance in my answer, and the `Get b` is passed as the `Serialize x` constraint. The `Serialize a => Serialize (Free FooF a)` instance from my answer has `get :: Get (Free FooF a)` where the `Get a` was passed in by the `Serialize a` constraint. Note that you can't get closer to the ideal type for `reverseIterM` than that, unless you have a way to get the `a` out of the monad `m`.

Comment: @Cirdec sorry ... won't be able to work on this this week ... I'll just mark your answer as accepted for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Types

It sounds like you might be looking for the composition of functors, which lives in the [transformers](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers) package in `Data.Functor.Compose`:

```
newtype Compose f g a = Compose { getCompose :: f (g a) }
```

If I understand your two questions correctly, you want to add things before and after something else, and then parse the added data back out. We'll make a type for adding things before and after something else

```
data Surrounded a b c = Surrounded a c b
  deriving (Functor)

surround :: a -> b -> c -> Surrounded a b c
surround a b c = Surrounded a c b
```

Now, supposing the data before something else is a `String` and the data after something else is an `Int`, you're looking for the type:

```
Free (Compose (Surrounded String Int) FooF) :: * -> *
```

### Instances

All that remains is to make `Serialize` instances for `FooF x`, `Surrounded a b c`, `Compose f g x`, and `Free f a`. The first three of these are easy and can be derived by the [cereal package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/cereal):

```
deriving instance Generic (FooF x)
instance Serialize x => Serialize (FooF x)

deriving instance Generic (Surrounded a b c)
instance (Serialize a, Serialize b, Serialize c) => Serialize (Surrounded a b c)

deriving instance Generic (Compose f g a)
instance (Serialize (f (g a))) => Serialize (Compose f g a)
```

If we try to do the same for `Free`, we would write `instance (Serialize a, Serialize (f (Free f a))) => Serialize (Free f a)`. We'd run into `UndecidableInstances` territory; to make a `Serialize` instance for `Free`, we first must have a `Serialize` instance for `Free`. We'd like to prove by induction that the instance already exists, but to do so, we'd need to be able to check that `f a` has a `Serialize` instance for all `a`s that have a `Serialize` instance.

#### Serialize1

To check that a functor has a `Serialize` instance as long as it's argument has a `Serialize` instance, we introduce a new type class, `Serialize1`. For those functors whose `Serialize` instance was already defined based on a `Serialize` instance for the argument, we can generate the new serialize instance by `default`.

```
class Serialize1 f where
    put1 :: Serialize a => Putter (f a)
    get1 :: Serialize a => Get (f a)

    default put1 :: (Serialize a, Serialize (f a)) => Putter (f a)
    put1 = put

    default get1 :: (Serialize a, Serialize (f a)) => Get (f a)
    get1 = get
```

The first two functors, `FooF` and `Surround a b`, can use the default instances for the new class:

```
instance Serialize1 FooF

instance (Serialize a, Serialize b) => Serialize1 (Surrounded a b)
```

`Compose f g` needs a bit of help.

```
-- Type to help defining Compose's Serialise1 instance
newtype SerializeByF f a = SerializeByF { unSerialiseByF :: f a }

instance (Serialize1 f, Serialize a) => Serialize (SerializeByF f a) where
    put = put1 . unSerialiseByF
    get = fmap SerializeByF get1

instance (Serialize1 f) => Serialize1 (SerializeByF f)
```

Now we can define a `Serialize1` instance for `Compose f g` in terms of serializing by the other two `Serialize1` instances. `fmap SerializeByF` tags `f`'s inner data to be serialized by `g`'s `Serialize1` instance.:

```
instance (Functor f, Serialize1 f, Serialize1 g) => Serialize1 (Compose f g) where
    put1 = put . SerializeByF . fmap SerializeByF . getCompose
    get1 = fmap (Compose . fmap unSerializeByF . unSerializeByF ) get
```

#### Serialize Free

Now we should be equipped to make a `Serialize` instance for `Free f a`. We will borrow the serialization of `Either a (SerializeByF f (Free f a))`.

```
toEitherRep :: Free f a => Either a (SerializeByF f (Free f a))
toEitherRep (Pure a) = Left a
toEitherRep (Free x) = Right (SerializeByF x)

fromEitherRep :: Either a (SerializeByF f (Free f a)) => Free f a
fromEitherRep = either Pure (Free . unSerializeByF)

instance (Serialize a, Serialize1 f) => Serialize (Free f a) where
    put = put . toEitherRep    
    get = fmap fromEitherRep get

instance (Serialize1 f) => Serialize1 (Free f)
```

### Example

Now we can serialize and deserialize things like:

```
example :: Free (Compose (Surrounded String Int) FooF) ()
example = Free . Compose . surround "First" 1 . Foo "FirstFoo" . Free . Compose . surround "Second" 2 . Bar 22 . Pure $ ()
```

### Boilerplate

The above requires the following extensions

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DefaultSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE StandaloneDeriving #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
```

and the following libraries:

```
import Control.Monad.Free
import Data.Functor.Compose
import Data.Serialize
import GHC.Generics
```

Comment: uff ... that's a lot to chew on. I honestly can't tell if this is useful to me yet.

Comment: `Compose` and `Surrounded` just add something like what you were doing in your other question. If you just want something that works along the lines of `Serialize a` => `Serialize (Free FooF a)`, you don't need them. You still need `SerializeByF` and `Serialize1` for the `Serialize (Free f a)` instance.

The same code could be written more easily without the extra types and type classes, slightly similar to what was done with `iterM` in the other question, but then we can't (remotely easily) use the type class based cereal library.

Comment: Actually that was what I was hoping for ... but I could not make up something like a "reverse iterM". Something like "run this `Get (Surround x y (Foo()))` n times and combine the results in one big `Surround x y (Foo())`".

Comment: iterM goes from a tree (Free) to a list by traversing the tree.  "reverse iterM" wouldn't go back to a single big flat list from the serialized list; the inverse operation would build the Free tree from the list, with the extra stuff wrapped around each step. Imagine if we inverted `doFooFExtra :: before -> after -> FooF (M a) -> M a`. It'd look something like `M a -> (before, after, FooF (M a))`.